# Can I dispatch events immediately/manually when dispatchPeriod is used with Google Analytics?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-analytics

Is it possible to dispatch (send) events manually by calling `[[GANTracker sharedTracker] dispatch]` even though `GANTracker` was instantiated with `dispatchPeriod` set to e.g. 10 seconds?

My understanding of Google Analytics iOS framework is that upon calling `trackEvent:action:label:value:withError:` method the event is not actually sent, but rather queued internally in `GANTracker` which will send it when `dispatchPeriod` expires. In other words, `GANTracker` collects events, page views etc. and will send them in burst every X seconds as per positive value of `dispatchPeriod`. Am I right?

Now, the documentation says that in order to manually dispatch (send) events to server, I need to instantiate `GANTracker` with `dispatchPeriod` set to `-1`. Is it really necessary? Can't I have best of both worlds? I thought calling `[[GANTracker sharedTracker] dispatch]` will send events regardless of dispatch period...

edit: I know, I could test it, but 24hrs delay period for data propagation is a bit long...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question, maybe someone will find it useful:

- **yes**, it is possible to use `dispatch` when tracker is started with `dispatchPeriod` > 0.
- I've tested it and GA events dispatched that way are visible in GA.